# SVG is taking up extra space and margin is not working on text element

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following SVG code:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100px">
  <text x="50%" y="60%" text-anchor="middle" style="">Name</text>
</svg>
```

This gives the following result. Too much extra space below the name. No matter what I try I cannot reduce it. Setting custom height cuts the name from the top.

[image]

If I change the height the Name gets cut from the top and margin is not working on text element.

```
<svg width="100%" height="40px">
  <text x="50%" y="60%" text-anchor="middle" style="margin-top: 10px;">Name</text>
</svg>
```

[image]

What is the issue?

Comment: Try this: use a viewBox attrubute for the svg element for example viewBox="0 0 40 24" and delete the width and the height attributes. If you are using this viewBox value the center of the svg canvas is in the point x="20" (40/2) y="12" (24/2). Use this to center the text instead of the actuals values ( x="50%" y="50%").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the dy property of the text element.

```
<svg width="100%" height="100px" >
  <text x="50%" y="60%" text-anchor="middle" dy="10px">Name</text>
</svg>
```